# Saving to User Photo Library Silently Fails

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I was trying to save an image to the user camera roll on my iPhone using this code:

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, nil, nil, nil)`

But despite not crashing or giving an error, it was failing. I made sure the image was a valid (not nil) UIImage, and it was. So then I tried implementing the completion handler like so:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

// ....

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR! ", error!.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

But this still didn't give me an error. Finally, I tried running on the simulator. This then gave me the following errors:

`Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died`

`Error! Write failed`

What is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 9):

I came across [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/4ek50j/app_cannot_save_to_camera_roll_even_with/?sort=top) which says that in order to run `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, the UIImage "must be CGImage-backed". So to work around, I wrote the following code to convert my UIImage into a CIImage, then into a CGImage, and back to a UIImage:

```
let ciImage = self.image!.ciImage
let context = CIContext()
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage!, from: ciImage!.extent)
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

This finally worked and saved to camera roll as expected!

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have come across the issue. Based on previous experience with CG+CI, I was anticipating it had something to with CI-Backed vs. CG-Backed.